# Partition problem on installation

Tags: installation, partitioning

I am trying to install Ubuntu 11 to dual-boot with Windows 7 (my main os).

Here is screenshot of disk management on Windows:

[image: im1]

As you can see I already shrinked volume D: for 16gb, where I am about to install ubuntu. However, in Ubuntu installation, I see no partitions at all.

Then, I launched Disk utility, and here what it showed:

[image: im2]

Check the size of last out-of-nowhere partition. Obviously something is wrong with my partition table. What can I do? Thanks.

Comment: Something is definitely wrong with Disk Utility, See this http://img6.imagebanana.com/img/65v9bcgh/Selection_001.png

Comment: Can you reupload the image?

Comment: Why reupload? Ok, I'll upload it to imgur http://i.imgur.com/zJsKF.png

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/yZOi8.png here is what GParted shows :-( I think I need some utility to run under Windows for fixing the partition table...

Comment: Just looked in Gparted, mine is exactly the same, shows "Unallocated".

Comment: Shouldn't it be showing right stuff? And how did you install Ubuntu then? Or you don't have win7?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, figured it out.

Under Windows, I backed up all the data on D, then removed it, and also removed "recovery partition". Then, I recreated D, so I got

unallocated (15gb), C, D, unallocated(16gb)

After that, Ubuntu found every partition just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I would rather suspect a bug in Disk Utility. Start gparted and check if same problem occurs. If not, disregard.

Comment: But then how do I install it, if there is no partitions at all at installation menu?

Comment: you can unset the the bootflag in gparted. The Installer from the Live-CD will prompt you to make partitions or (by your choice create them automatically).

Comment: I posted gparted screenshot in comments to my question, check it, please.

Comment: And what's the problem? Now you can either create partitions yourself or have the ubuntu-install create them by selecting the unallocated space there. When the installation is through, you should be fine.

Comment: But unallocated space is my whole hdd... wouldn't it ruin everything?